# Do Namibian citizens require a visa for short entry to Ghana?

Tags: visas, ghanaian-citizens, namibia, ghana

The purpose of travel is to attend a conference; duration of stay is ~ 1 week.

- [Ghana High Commission UK](https://www.ghanahighcommissionuk.com/passports/VisaApplication.aspx) says *no*
- [Ghana High Commission Windhoek](http://ghanahighcommission.com.na/visa-services/) says *yes*
- [Kotoka Airport Accra](https://www.accra-airport.com/visa_on_arrival_ghana.php) says *no*

It's a tiny bit confusing.

The Namibian High Commission in Accra [says that Ghanaians require visas to enter Namibia](https://www.namibiahc-ghana.org/about1), suggesting that the converse would be true.

Comment: No, according to Timatic https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client_post.cgi

Comment: @Traveller That URL is for `POST` requests - where did you enter the data?

Comment: Sorry, try here https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html or here https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/LK

Answer (score 3):

I was asking to ascertain the situation for two Namibian citizens who travelled to Accra from Windhoek in August 2019.

- In Windhoek, the Ghana High Commission issued them visas at US$120 each.
- On arrival in Accra, immigration officials were puzzled and told them that they did not require visas to enter.

That's annoying and disappointing, and was quite an unnecessary burden to bear for students of very limited means. I doubt that there is anything that can be done about it now though.